# Angularfire facebook OAuth pop up not working as it should

Tags: angularjs, facebook-login, angularfire, facebook-oauth

I am using login with Facebook in my app. When users click the login button the Facebook login pop up flashes and logs in users without showing the pop up and asking users if they want to log in first. In summary, once users click the login button they are logged in automatically. I am not sure why this is happening. The authentication works fine and facebook returns the authData object. It is just the pop up that is not working as I want.

Here is the controller:

```
//============AUTHENTICATION CONTROLLER============
myApp.controller("MyAuthCtrl", ["$scope","$rootScope","$firebaseAuth","$location",
  function($scope, $rootScope, $firebaseAuth, $location) {
    var ref = new Firebase("myfirebaseUrl");
    $scope.authObj = $firebaseAuth(ref);

        //============FACEBOOK AUTHENTICATION SCRIPT============
        ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
            if (error) 
            {
                console.log("Login Failed!", error);

                //the function below is necessary to change window location
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $location.path('/home');
                });

            } else 
            {
                $rootScope.currentUser = authData;

                //console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
                //console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider + "name: " + authData.facebook.displayName);

                //the function below is necessary to change window location
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $location.path('/events');   
                });
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Here are the routes:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute","firebase"]);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when("/events",
    {
        controller:"eventsController",
        templateUrl:"partials/events.html"
    })
    .when("/home",
    {
        templateUrl:"partials/home.html"
    })
    .when("/auth",
    {
        controller:"MyAuthCtrl",
        templateUrl:"partials/home.html"
    })
    .otherwise(
    {
        redirectTo:"/home"
    })
});
```

Comment: If the user is already logged into Facebook, then we short circuit the login process and just return the auth data to you. Try logging the user out of Facebook (not just via unauth(), but actually logging them out of Facebook. Then you should see the popup again and have to type in credentials.

Comment: @jacobawenger That is what I realized right after I wrote the question. Thank you for the comment.